# configure externa database in war file jpa rest spring

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa

I'm working with the Accessing JPA Data with REST spring guide, with mySql database, in the document http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.1.5.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html explain how to connect with the external database, that basically is create the application.properties in which the connection is configured, in my case is something like the following:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/backbone
spring.datasource.username=myUser
spring.datasource.password=UserPass5665
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
hibernate.format_sql=true
hibernate.show_sql=true\u200F
```

That file is in the src folder, and obviously in the classpath is referenced the mysql jdbc jar.

when deploying the project in spring tool suite it runs and comunicate with the database, but, when I take the war file and install it to run in tomcat it can't communicate with the database, so, where or how I have to configure or put the application.properties file and the jdbc mysql jar?

Thanks for your collaboration and best regards

Comment: Can you list out the full path of where this file resides in your war?  Something such as /WEB-INF/foo/application.properties

Comment: that is the problem, in the spring tool suite I put it at the src folder at the same level of the packages, but when I compile it, using the gradle build utility, I open the war but I couldn't find the file

I don't know if I have to put it in a special path or something